# Chart JS Line insert Picture

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, canvas, chart.js

Simple Setup:
I have a RoR Application and a ChartJS Line Diagramm.
I want to add a Picture at a specific place but also text.
In the progress of the RoR Application answers of users will show up after time. Later the answer of two people will be shown, who is closer to the Average.
In my case I only need to know how a Picture could rendered inside.

[Picture What it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqGnv.png)

Here is my actual Code:

```js
var points = [];
    
       var data = {
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Antworten',
            data: points,
            radius: 6,
            borderColor: "#000000",
            borderWidth: 2,
            backgroundColor: "#FF0000"
        },
        {
            label: "",
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,1)",
            borderColor: "rgba(0,0,0,1)",
            borderCapStyle: 'butt',
            borderDash: [0],
            borderDashOffset: 0.0,
            showLine: true,
            borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
            pointBorderColor: "rgba(0,0,0,1)",
            pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(1,0,0,1)",
            pointBorderWidth: 8,
            pointHoverRadius: 5,
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(0,0,0,1)",
            pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
            pointRadius: 1,
            pointStyle: "circle",
            pointHitRadius: 10,
            data: [{
                x: 0,
                y: 0
            },{
                x: 100,
                y: 0
            }],
            borderColor: "#000000",
            borderWidth: 5,
            backgroundColor: "#FF0000"
        }
        ]
    };
    
        window.onload = function() {
            var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
            window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data,
                options: {
                    legend: {
                        display: false
                    },
                    showLines: false,
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                            type: 'linear',
                            gridLines: {
                                display: false
                            },
                            position: 'bottom',
                            ticks: {
                                max: 100,
                                min: 0,
                                stepSize: 10
                            }
                        }],
                        yAxes: [{
                            display: false,
                            ticks: {
                                max: 1,
                                min: 0,
                                stepSize: 1
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Found an Answer:
Here my solution

```
var user_a = new Image();
user_a.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/fwhrCBs.png';

var data = {
    datasets: [
    {
        label: 'Spieler 1',
        data: user_a_answer,
        radius: 1,
        borderColor: "#000000",
        borderWidth: 2,
        pointStyle: user_a,
    }]
```